# Django urls. Why aren't urls.py included with new app?

Tags: python, django

Just curious, especially since Django is all about the DRY principle, why doesn't it include urls.py with creation of new app?
Maybe it's just my case(I'm relatively new to Django), but at least 90% of the time, I need to create a urls.py file, which seems quite repetitive to me. There are other actions while doing a web project/app that I've found repetitive, but the URLs seems fundamental to the structure, so don't see what the harm would be for it to be included with the new app creation.

Any thoughts, insights?

Comment: Because they expect us to use main urls.py and it takes too long for us. So we are adding urls.py to make everything easy. It is not same way but you can ask same question for python too. Why we have to install too common framework everytime? why python doesn't include all this frameworks?

Comment: As the answer says, you can use another template that works better for you. Personally, I'd prefer to have `views` and `models` and `tests` in packages too, but that's not the default either :)

Comment: I think [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is more about avoiding duplicating code, not avoiding repetitive actions when writing it.

Comment: I understand the DRY is related to the coding culture/practice, I was just thinking shouldn't it be extended to most common use case.
So all of you who have answered have not had to add additional urls.py on a regular basis?
If the majority of you have had to and still do, then that is an obvious use case that is not being addressed.
It's not about being spoonfed, mind you, I just find it irksome especially if Django is WEB framework, I believe there are certain not too deep things that can be added for a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

This is default startapp [template](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/app_template) behavior that Django team decided it is minimal ( not everyone would create urls.py in each app)

You can customize this behavior by providing your own app_template that suits your needs

From [startapp](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp) documentation:

```
django-admin startapp --template=/Users/jezdez/Code/my_app_template myapp
```